# Tourism visa for Philippines for India

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visa-free-entry, philippines

I will be travelling to Philippines in December and i have been going through visa free travel requirements for it.
As per the Philippines consulate FAQ [link](https://newdelhipe.dfa.gov.ph/images/2018/Visa/FAQs-for-short-staying-visitors.pdf) , if you hold a valid Japan visa and meet other requirements then you don't require visa to enter Philippines. I do hold Japan visa and meet other requirements as well.

But i am quite skeptical and my worry is what if immigration officer refuses entry without visa.

It will be very helpful if someone can share their experience or guide me on how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an Indian citizen. I have used Singapore resident card for Visa-free travel to the Philippines. I used Cebu pacific airlines for my travel, starting from Singapore. I visited Cebu and Manila on a single visit.

The document verification is pretty straight forward. You need the following documents.

1. Passport
2. Valid visa from any of the countries mentioned.
3. Return tickets
4. Proof of accommodation.

The airline is aware of the document requirements. You can carry a printout from the site, in case some ignorant gate agent is not aware.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For how many days did you stay? My plan is for 20 days. So i may require 7 days extension on top of 14 days generally given.

Comment: If that is the case, it's better to take a visa. I stayed only for 4 days.

The gate agent usually considers only 14 days. Also the immigration authorities. The visa for Philipines is not much expensive or hard to get.

Answer (score 1):

Timatic, the system used by airlines, confirms your understanding:

“The following are exempt from holding a visa:

Nationals of India traveling as a tourist with a passport valid for a minimum of 6 months beyond the period of intended stay, for a maximum stay of 14 days. They must have a valid tourist, business or resident visa issued by Australia, Canada, Japan, Singapore, USA, United Kingdom, or a Schengen Member State .”

Additional information:

Length of stay is calculated by starting on the next day after the day of arrival in the Philippines.

Extension of stay possible for an additional 7 days, for nationals of India entering the Philippines when holding a valid tourist, business or resident visa or permanent residence permit issued by Australia, Canada, Japan, Singapore, USA, United Kingdom, or a Schengen Member State .

Source: https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b